# Users and Roles

Tags: sql, sqlite

The following two tables are used to define users and their respective roles:

```
TABLE users
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  userName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL

TABLE roles
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  role VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
```

The `users_roles` table should contain the mapping between each user and their roles. Each user can have many roles, and each role can have many users.

Modify the provided SQLite create table statement so that:

Only users from the users table can exist within `users_roles`.
Only roles from the roles table can exist within `users_roles`.
A user can only have a specific role once.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1):

Following DDL script will attain your objective

```
drop table if exists users;
drop table if exists roles;
drop table if exists users_roles;


create table users (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  userName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
); 

create table roles (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  role VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

create table users_roles(
    user_role_id integer not null primary key,
    user_id integer not null,
    role_id integer not null,
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(role_id) REFERENCES roles(id),
    UNIQUE (user_id, role_id)
);
```